# Error after installing Android Studio 4.2

Tags: android, android-studio

After I installed Android Studio 4.2 (Stable Version), When I run it the error occurs:  `Corrupted Installation with detail: Missing Essential Plugin org.jetbrains.android.`

I clean manually the existing components of the previous Android. Then I uninstall again the Android Studio 4.2 then reinstalled it again. But, the same error appears.

Any suggestion why I am facing an installation issue in Android 4.2.